# Automapper formatter being called twice for single property

Tags: automapper

I have a problem with an automapper formatter being called twice and using the value it resolved to on the first run as the source on the second run and causing bad results.

My automapper profile contains the following global string formatter

```
Mapper.ForSourceType<string>().AddFormatter<StandardStringFormatter>();
```

I have another formatter for a specific string property.  DhcpEnabledFlagFormatter turns a one character code into a meaningful string.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<NetInterface, NetInterfaceList>()
      .ForMember(x => x.DhcpEnabledFlag,
       o => o.AddFormatter<DhcpEnabledFlagFormatter>());
```

DhcpEnabledFlagFormatter gets called twice.  On the second pass, it uses the meaningful string it resolved to as the source value and then always returns "None" which is default response of the Formatter.

If I remove the global StandardStringFormatter from my automapper profile, the problem goes away and DhcpEnabledFlagFormatter is only called once.

I know I can solve problem by turning DhcpEnabledFlagFormatter into a custom resolver, but I am curious if there is another option or if this is a known bug.